# Javascript method defining failed

Tags: javascript

I do not understand what i got wrong.
I am using javascript.

Edit: I realised that there is a javascript console in modern browsers, so i apologise for the trouble caused.

```
var name = ""
function makelayer(name){
  var myLayer = document.createElement('div');
  myLayer.id = name;
  myLayer.style.position = 'absolute';
}
function position(x,y){
  myLayer.id = name;
  myLayer.style.left= x + "px";
  myLayer.style.top = y+ "px";
}
function size(w,h){
  myLayer.id = name;
  myLayer.style.width = w +'px';
  myLayer.style.height = h+'px';
}
function display(type){
  myLayer.id = name;
  myLayer.style.display = type;
}
function add(){
  myLayer.id = name;
  myLayer.innerHTML = '<img src="stickmanbackground.png" />'
  myLayer.style.zIndex = 99;
  myLayer.style.filter = 'alpha(opacity = 100)';
  document.body.appendChild(myLayer);
}
makelayer("name");
position(0,0);
size(500,500);
display("block");
add();
```

Can someone explain to me where are the mistakes? Thanks.
Nothing appeared on the screen...

Comment: `;` these are required.

Comment: it's js, `;` not REQUIRED

Comment: myLayer isn't defined ...

Comment: For future reference: if you're using Chrome try opening the JavaScript console (Tools > JavaScript console) which will show you which error you're getting, and which line of code is causing it.

Comment: leonneo, when you ask "where are the mistakes", you should also describe any error messages you get when you try run it (use a JavaScript console to see the errors; all modern browsers have them).

Comment: All i saw is a blank screen and i didnt know theres a javascript console. Sorry for the trouble caused.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Move variable out of function scope:

```
var myLayer;

function makelayer(name){
  myLayer = document.createElement('div');
  myLayer.id = name;
  myLayer.style.position = 'absolute';
}
```

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/jQfGP/)

Comment: Can you run it on jfiddle and give me the link? Thank you very much.

Comment: @leonneo You are welcome :) jsfiddle link is provided in updated question. (image is not visible because `stickmanbackground.png` resource does not exist on fiddle)